# sIFR slector for li:hover effect

Tags: javascript, html, css, sifr

I have a menu

```
<div id="nav">
  <ul>
    <li><span><a href="/index.asp">Home</a></span></li>
    <li><span><a href="/aboutus.asp">About Us</a></span></li>
    <li><span><a href="/whatWeDo.asp" id="whatWeDo">What We Do</span></a>
        <ul id="sideNav">   
           <li><a href="/page1.asp"tabindex="15">page 1</a></li>
           <li><a href="/page2.asp"tabindex="16">page 2</a></li>
           <li><a href="/page3.asp"tabindex="17">page 3</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>  
   <li><span><a href="/studies.asp">Studies</a></span></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

I am trying to create a pop out menu the CSS that does this is:

```
#nav ul{
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
#nav ul li{
    list-style: none;
    font-size: 16px;
    width:170px;
    padding:0px 0px 10px 0px;
}
#nav ul li ul li{
    font-size: 13px;
}
#nav ul li ul{
    display: none;
}
.showMenu, #nav ul li:hover ul{        
    width:220px;
    padding:7px;
    background: #F2F2F2;
    border:1px solid #F2F2F2;
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    left: 85px;
    top: 30px;
}

#nav ul li ul li{
    padding:2px 0px 2px 0px;
}
```

I am tring to replace the items within both lists but they have different stlyes. I can replace the top level elements easy enough but its the pop out menu that I can not replace the links on.

my SIFR code:

```
sIFR.replace(futura, {
    selector: '#nav ul li span',
    css: ['.sIFR-root {}a{ color:#639463;text-decoration:none; font-size: 16px; font-weight:bold;} a:hover{color:#83C000;text-decoration:underline;}'],
    wmode: 'transparent'
});
```

Comment: sorry im not helping you here but i want to give you the tipp of using something similiar to http://www.fontsquirrel.com/ to use non-webstandard fonts

Comment: I've looked into @fonts which is what fontsquirrel use i point you to this post: http://stackoverflow.com/q/4061647/1122811

Comment: @font works for IE7+,Safari,FF,Chrome ... the 2% remaining getting the fallback font... i see no problem except you have the font as ttf, otf, dfont or windows post script.

Comment: @ggzone one problem might be the font license - many font foundries don't allow font embedding, but do allow sIFR or image replacement techniques.

Comment: if the customer dont want to pay the license hes getting a web-standard font... its easy; sIFR is kinda "old" techniquie and has some major issues coming with it. bit better is cufon but kinda same problem... font styles, breaks, text copy and so on...

Answer (score 0):

I think part of your problem is that sIFR needs displaying elements to act on.
If you can't use @font styles, I can telly ou that I've successfully used Cufon in this way on a small job, as seen here: http://www.reneworganicbeauty.com/

It's still a bit finicky, and colour changes take a bit of fiddling, but at least it works ok in menus.